# Android エミュレーターへAPKファイルがインストール出来ない

Tags: android, cordova

CordovaでAndroidアプリの開発をしています。

```
cordova run --emulator
```

で、デバッグビルドは無事にエミュレーターにインストールすることが出来るのですが

```
cordova run --release --emulator
```

とすると、インストールに失敗してしまいます。
stack traceを見ても不明なエラーとなり原因がわかりません。

お力添えのほどよろしくお願いします。

◆ 開発環境
Windows8.1
JDK1.8.0_05
cordova: 5.1.1

◆ ログ

```
Running command: cmd "/s /c "~\app\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --release --emulator""
ANDROID_HOME=~\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
Running: ~\app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b ~\app\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
～中略～
:cdvBuildRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.134 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    ~\app\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: ~\app\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk

~\app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Failed to launch app on emulator: Failed to install apk to emulator:    pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-release-unsigned.apk


Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]



ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Installing app on emulator...
>   Using apk: ~\app\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk

android-release-**unsigned**.apk とあるので、アプリが署名されていないのが原因ではないでしょうか？

また、エミュレーター側のセキュリティ設定で、提供元不明のアプリのインストールの許可をすれば、未署名でもインストールが可能かもしれません。

Comment: 提供元不明のアプリのインストール許可はされていました。

`cordova run --release --emulator`は想定していない動作なのか、署名されたものをインストールする方法がわかりませんでした。

手動でandroid-release-unsigned.apkに`jarsigner`, `zipalign`まで掛けて`adb install`したところ無事エミュレーターにインストールすることができました。

ありがとうございました。